# How can I use boolean expressions to fix this code?

Tags: java

I would like to create a method that crops a specified number of characters off of either the front or the back of or both the front and back of a provided string of characters. If the number of characters to be cropped is too long given the length of the text it returns as "Can't crop more than the length of the text."

The parameters are supposed to do the following:

```
@param  String text - a piece of text of any length containig ascii characters
@param  int howMany - number of characters to be cropped
@param  boolean front - true if characters should be cropped from the front of text, false don't crop from front
@param  boolean back - true if characters should be cropped from the back of text, false don't crop from back
```

I currently have this code but the program crashes especially when displaying the "Cropped (both):" Say String text said "sammy" and the int howMany said "4", well the if statement would not display because int howMany is not greater than String text, BUT... the program collapses when displaying cropped (both) because it is not possible to crop 4 from the front and 4 from the back, that results in -3. I am sure I have to use boolean values here but I am not exactly sure how I am supposed to incorporate them in, they are part of my parameters but I have not used them. Can you please explain to me how I can fix this code to do the desired task? This method is called upon by the main method and arguments are passed on from that method to this one. I passed on true for all the boolean expression. This is the code I have...

```
public static String cropText(String text, int howMany, boolean front, boolean back)
{
  String result = "";

  if (howMany > text.length())
  {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Can't crop more than the length of the text");
  }

  else
  {
     System.out.println("Cropped (both):");
     System.out.println("-----------");
     System.out.println(text.substring(howMany, text.length() - howMany));
     System.out.println("--------------");

     System.out.println("Cropped (front):");
     System.out.println("-----------");
     System.out.println(text.substring(howMany, text.length() - 0));
     System.out.println("--------------");
     front = true;

     System.out.println("Cropped (back):");
     System.out.println("-----------");
     System.out.println(text.substring(0, text.length() - howMany));
     System.out.println("--------------");
     back = true;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: You'd need to test your string BEFORE you try to substring it, to see if it's actually long enough to accomodate either trim parameter.

Comment: Your code looks very vague. You are doing everything in the else loop without any coditional checks

Comment: Not that it answers your question but you have to check whether `front` and `back` are true, not set them to be so. Setting them within the function will have no effect at all, as outside of the function you won't be changing them.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if (howMany > text.length())
```

You need to see whether you are asked for cropping on zero, one, or both sides.

```
sides = 0;
if (front) sides++;
if (back) sides++;
if(howMany * sides > text.length())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you crop from *both* sides, you don't crop `howMany` from the text, but `2*howMany`. So, you have to change two things:

- Change the `if` condition:

  ```
  if ((front && back && (howMany*2 > text.length())) || howMany > text.length())
  ```
- Put your `println` in conditional blocks:

  ```
  if (front && back) {
      System.out.println("Cropped (both):");
      System.out.println("-----------");
      System.out.println(text.substring(howMany, text.length() - howMany));
      System.out.println("--------------");
  }

  if (front) {
      System.out.println("Cropped (front):");
      System.out.println("-----------");
      System.out.println(text.substring(howMany, text.length() - 0));
      System.out.println("--------------");
  }

  if (back) {
      System.out.println("Cropped (back):");
      System.out.println("-----------");
      System.out.println(text.substring(0, text.length() - howMany));
      System.out.println("--------------");
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be ignoring the booleans `front` and `back` so far; those should be relevant for how the function works too. The simplest way to solve this is probably something like the following pseudocode:

```
if(front should be cropped) {
    if(front can be cropped) {
        crop front
    } else {
        say you can't
    }
}

same for the back

if(front and back should be cropped) {
    if(front and back can be cropped) {
        crop front and back
    } else {
        say you can't
    }
}
```

This code can be optimized but should be easy enough to understand this way.